# Can I have a proof of the theorem below in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

The necessary and sufficient condition for the transcendental inequality 
$[x \leq a + b e^{-x}] ;\; a,b$ real, to have no solutions $x \geq 0$ is
$$
[a+b < 0]; \; \text{for }b \geq -1,$$
and
$$
[1+b e^{(1-a)}] < 0\; \text{if } b < -1.
$$

Comment: I am not at all familiar with the question asked here.. I just tried to latex it to make it readable ... Please make sure i have not changed your point..

Comment: *Gimme Gimme Gimme (a proof after midnight)*... Tries? Thoughts? Context?

Comment: Is it related to numerical analysis?